# DATAFILETYPE doesn't work when INSERT unicode characters by Using BULK in SQL

Tags: sql, unicode, bulk

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Infosp1 FROM  'D:\test.txt' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='widechar' ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

> D:\test.txt:
>
> BácHồng,Chanh,3
>
> BácHồng,Ớt,1
>
> BácHồng,Càchua,2
>
> CôPhượng,Càchua,23
>
> CôPhượng,Ớt,2
>
> BácThanh,Càchua,5
>
> BácThanh,Chanh,5

[__Click to show image ___I tried so many ways, i can't use DATAFILETYPE ='widechar'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivf2d.png)

Comment: What are your data types on infosp1? I tested with your data using nvarchar(100) columns and it was successful.

Comment: Second test I used varchar(100) columns and was not successful. I'm pretty sure your issue is the target column data types need to be unicode.

Comment: >Nvarchar(25), sir.

Comment: if query normally, must have sight `N'unicode'` but my case is bulk